# Visual Studio 2012 SSDT - How do I create/manage tables now?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-data-tools

I'm trying out Visual Studio 2012 and so far it's good but I created database project, added database *.mdf file to my App_Data and tried to create simple database with relations and I have no clue what to do next. I can't even name my database.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272680(v=vs.103).aspx - AFAIK this article shows how to add relations but I can't find any `Foreign Keys` node. And also, why can't I edit name? VS2010 database management was so easy and intuitive, now I don't understand how to work with it.

More visual representation of my question and my simple table for example.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table name you can change in `Properties` window:
[image: table properties]
relations by right clicking on `Foreign Keys`:
[image: keys]
You can also modify sql in lower pane - all changes will be reflected in graphical tools. I'm find this useful e.g. when I want to copy some columns from one table to another.
You can also make changes on database with another tools, like SSMS (better FK tools I think) and then import this changes via `Schema Compare` by setting database as source and project as destination.

Comment: Name is grey for me, I can only edit name in SQL Project. And about foreign keys - I need to type them in T-SQL format now? It used to pop-up window where I would select my relations basically with mouse alone...

Comment: I can edit Table name in my vs, maybe you have  read only (unchecked?) file? Try change table name in sql pane.

Comment: Yes, you have to write your FK (fill text template with names). Then I usually prefer to do it in SSMS graphically and then import changes to project via Schema Compare .

Comment: That's unfortunate, wonder why they made it so different now. Well, I will use POCO approach then. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the database where you like to execute the query and then select add new query and execute the following query in it.

```
sp_rename 'oldtablename','newtablename'
```

Answer (score 1):

Not so far. Right clic on this element.
[image]

Comment: I need to type them in T-SQL, right? Because it used to pop-up window where I can map all relations basically by mouse within like 20 seconds... :(

Answer (score 0):

check out this answer:  [Visual Studio 2012 Database Designer - Has the functionality changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229731/visual-studio-2012-database-designer-am-i-missing-something)

I'm new to sql anyway if you right click the toolbar there is a "table designer" set of buttons but are all grayed out.  Not sure if to initiate them the db must be Online.