# Visual Query Designer not accessible in when connecting to SQL Server 2012 in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012

When I right click the Tables node in Server Explorer and choose "New Query", rather than seeing the visual designer, I now see a text designer with no obvious way to get to the visual designer (see screen shot).

[image: Visual Studio Screen Shot]

Notice how the Query Designer tools are all greyed out. Is there any way to get back to the visual designer?

If it makes a difference, the database I'm connecting to is SQL Server 2012 Express.

**EDIT**

I have done some more research and it appears I should be able to see the designer by just creating a new query (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172011.aspx). I can't find any option that may affect this behaviour. It also means I can't just edit a row in my test DB, which is driving me crazy!!!

**EDIT 2**

OK, the behaviour I get is based on the database I connect to. When I add a connection to an SQL Server 2008 database, right click and choose "New Query" I get the visual designer. When I connection to an SQL Server 2012 database and do **exactly the same thing** I get the text SQL editor with no access to a visual designer!!!

Comment: EDIT2 explains why I can't get the visual designer. Thanks. Lucky for me I still kept VS2010 on my machine. Perhaps there needs to be yet another "Make VS2012 work like VS2010" plugin / hack to sort this out.

Comment: Facing the same problems you describe here but no greying-out I think the latest VS2012 update now completely hides those buttons. It is extremely frustrating not having the ability to run a SELECT query and then make inline edits to the rows in the result set. Very regressive step by MS forcing me to go outside the VS interface to make small data corrections. I don't want to run an UPDATE query everytime I need to make a small correction to the data. Also this only appears to be affecting SQL 2012 connections not SQL 2008 RS as the poster pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft moved some of the Data tools into SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT).  That is a separate install, and it comes with a Visual Studio Extension.

Here's a link to another thread on Stack Overflow.

[Visual Studio 2012 Database Designer - Has the functionality changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229731/visual-studio-2012-database-designer-am-i-missing-something)

Comment: Thanks @Walt, I saw the other SO thread. Please tell me if I'm wrong, but it seems strange to me that the tools have been moved but the buttons are still there (just disabled). Just to be clear, are you saying the only way I can get a visual query designer in VS2012 is to install SSDT?

Comment: I'm not sure that its the only way.  Microsoft messaging around this change has been non existent.

Comment: It appears that Microsoft have deliberately removed many of the data tools when connecting to SQL Server 2012 (see http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/751877/missing-database-diagram-node-in-both-sql-server-object-explorer-and-server-explorer-data-connection-to-same-sql-server). Have just installed SQL Server Management Studio and I'm using that now. :(

Comment: They haven't moved them as such, rather completely ditched them. Even in SSDT I can't make inline edits to data derived from an SQL Query. I can only make such direct edits to the top 1000 rows.

Answer (score 2):

While creating the database connection to SQL Server, select the .NET Data Provider as  - **.NET Framework Data Provider for OLEDB** to get the Visual Query Designer in VS 2012 !

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to replicate this with having a database project created first and here are the results:

[image]

Everything works as expected.
The results were the same without any active project.

Comment: You might consider running a profiler and capturing the commands VS sends towards the database in order to see if they are supported on the Express edition.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured this one out.  You must uninstall all references to prior versions of visual studio and microsoft sql server.  Dealt with this issue for the past two days after a server upgrade.  I downloaded and installed the following software in this exact order and it resolved my issue.

[Business Intelligence for visual studio 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36843)

[SQL Server Express 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062)

Hope this helps put this pesky little issue to bed once and for all.